# Deploy App to Heroku - I got Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I worked my first application looking at one tutorial for Mongo / Express / Node. App successfully worked on the localhost port:3000 with nodemon server.js.

I connected GitHub directly with Heroku and get message "Internal Server Error" every time.

I would appreciate if someone knows what the problem is. Although the application functioned on the computer, I wanted to learn how to deploy it on Heroku.

```
require("./models/db");

const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");

const employeeController = require("./controllers/employeeController");

var app = express();
app.use(
  bodyparser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
);
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "/views/"));
app.engine(
  "hbs",
  exphbs({
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "mainlayout",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/"
  })
);
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env)
});

app.use("/employee", employeeController);
```

Answer (score 1):

from your post I can only guess a number of things that could be wrong. Try using `heroku logs -t` in your terminal (if you have logged in on the heroku cli on your terminal) and comment what you see. It could be that your npm start command is using nodemon (which shouldn't be used for production). It could also be that there is maybe something that isn't in your package.json therefore not being installed on Heroku. If you post what you get on that terminal command I can maybe help you further :)

Comment: It seems that there are two things that are going wrong , possibly related to each other. The first one is there seems to be a syntax error "Unexpected token (" with app.listen. Check to make sure you dont have an extra bracket somewhere or havent closed a bracket somewhere. Also, you define a route after app.listen, `app.use("/employee", employeeController)` you should generally not do this - define all the routes first then call app.listen. Another error I see is the mongo connection - you are probably trying to connect to your local DB (which isnt available on Heroku). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

for better debugging, you can see the Heroku server logs with the following command

```
Heroku logs -t -a <your app name>
```